# InvokeRepeat или FixedUpdate

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Я оптимизирую игру и у меня генерируется дорога в `FixedUpdate`, что лучше использовать `FixedUpdate` или `InvokeRepeat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Экономия на спичках. Но пару нюансов отмечу:

1. Частота срабатывания `FixedUpdate` непостоянна.
2. Вы не знаете, когда у вас вызовется `InvokeRepeat`: до/после/во время `FixedUpdate`.
3. `InvokeRepeating` использует рефлексию, если я правильно помню, что довольно-таки медленно на фоне `FixedUpdate`.
4. Если у вас уже используется `FixedUpdate` для чего-то, то лучше и дальше его использовать и `Time.fixedDeltaTime`.

Comment: Для `FixedUpdate` следует использовать `Time.fixedDeltaTime`

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский спасибо, поправил (: